# Access checkout sessions objects via without its ID

Tags: stripe-payments

I need to access the checkout sessions where I have the custom field value that my customers have entered during checkout.

I have their customer ID, invoice prefix, charge id, etc - yet I am unable to find their checkout ID from anywhere.

Is the only option to loop through checkout/sessions to find where the user id exists (or create a local database for this, or other workarounds), or is there also an endpoint through which I can access the checkout ID?

Alternatively, if I could access the value inserted to the custom_fields through any other ID - that would already do the trick.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to retrieve Checkout Session is configure a webhook endpoint and listening to `checkout_session.completed` event. Check [Checkout fulfillment Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders).